# Python Flask API - smtplib throws an error after deployment

Tags: python, flask, smtp, smtplib, flask-restx

I use an API with works fine on my local machine, but not when I deploy it. I can access the API correctly, but however, I am not able to run the `sendmail` function anymore. This is the code:

```
def is_valid_email(email):
    if len(email) > 7:
        return bool(
            re.match("^.+@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", email)
        )


def sendmail(name, email):

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = "Confirmation email"
    msg["From"] = "mymail.com"
    msg["To"] = email

    msg.set_content(
        f"Hallo {name},\n\nDanke für deine Email. Ich werde mich zeitnah um dein Anliegen kümmern.\n\nViele Grüße\nxxx"
    )

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login("mymail.com", "password")
        smtp.send_message(msg)


@api.route("/makerequest")
class MakeRequest(Resource):
    def post(self):
        name = request.get_json()["name"]
        email = request.get_json()["email"]
        text = request.get_json()["text"]

        if is_valid_email(email) is False:
            return {"message": "Invalid Email"}, 401

        sendmail(name, email)

        return {"message": "mail sent successfully"}, 200
```

This is the error I receive: `flask    | smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv\n5.7.14`

I don´t use a firewall currentl and the less secure apps are allowed.
The provided username and password are correct, they work on my local machine. What can be the reason that it does not work on my server and how to fix it?

Comment: allow less secure apps on your email settings

Comment: Well maybe your deployed environment/machine has ip blocked by google smtp service. My suggestion is to use leave email-sending headache to `sendgrid.com`

Comment: less secure apps are already allowed. I will go for mailgun... thank you everybody